# The mathematical split

Tags: mathematics

A mathematical split:

> Can you split 34 into two parts such that four-seventh of one of these parts equals two-fifths of the other?

This puzzle is from a book so I can't give you a link.

Comment: I don't really think this is a riddle. After all it's just a pair of simultaneous equation

Comment: Ok, but I can't delete it.

Comment: It's ok! No need to delete. It will likely be closed, but if you learn from your questions that get closed then it will help you make much better puzzles in the future!

Comment: I voted to close ;-)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Why did you answer it then? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor started on it thinking there might be a puzzle (like some trick to it where it can't be done mathematically) so tried simultaneous equations before realising... it was just that and by that point it had already been written up so :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple simultaneous equations:

> $4/7x = 2/5y$
> $x + y = 34$
>
> $x = 34 - y$
> $4/7(34 - y) = 2/5y$
> $136/7 - 4/7y = 2/5y$
> $34/35y = 136/7$
> $y = 20$
> $x = 14$

So the answer is

> Yes, 14 and 20

And to show its true:

> 4/7 of 14 is 4 lots of 2 which is 8.
> 2/5 of 20 is 2 lots of 4 which is 8.

Comment: It's much easier than that. Their ratio is $x:y :: \frac25:\frac47 :: 14:20$, so they are $\frac{14}{34}$ and $\frac{20}{34}$ of the total.